# svg image not renedered in django

Tags: html, django, svg

I have developed a django application to show svg image on browser.

I have vss image that i saved as svg and placed in media folder with appropriate settings

Problem: when i try to view the svg image through my django application , images not displayed.
To verify if my project setting are correct i look at  the page source and its having svg content.

When i directly access the svg file using full path to svg file , it appear correctly.

Also  when i create small svg file to draw circle at same location that is media and try to view it , it appeared on browser through my django application.

To me it look like svg file which i created from vss have some tags that contradict with html and hence not displaying svg image in browser.d

Comment: You need to post some example code somewhere.  The problem could be one of many things.  We would just be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `models.FileField` instead `models.ImageField`, and in your template use it as image tag. 
*The issue here is that Django uses the PIL library to validate that uploaded files really are images*
[more about this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14092)

And if you have troubles with render SVG images in browser, you should use third party library, e.g.  [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/)